# Unexpected identifier при выполнении кода

Tags: jquery

возникла проблема в исполнении довольно таки простого кода. Функция подразумевает под собой банальное изменение цвета фона дива, но из-за своей глупости и нубства не могу найти причину проблемы. Заранее благодарю.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button_1').click(function() { //first button
    $('.maincontent_1').css('background-color', 'blue');
    if $('.maincontent_1' 'background-color') == 'blue';
      $('.maincontent_1').css('background-color', 'pink');
  });
    $('#button_2').click(function() { //second button
        $('.maincontent_2').css('background-color', 'green');
    if $('.maincontent_1' 'background-color') == 'blue';
        $('.maincontent_2').css('background-color', 'red');
    else $('.maincontent_2').css('background-color', 'brown');
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #302E2D;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  padding: 30px;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}
.maincontent_1 {
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 17%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.maincontent_2 {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 3%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}
footer {
  padding: 30px 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
#button_1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#button_2 {
  background: white;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 1%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>main.sheet</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="t.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>Шапка</header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="maincontent_1">
            <p>dfgs sregsre gse sgsr gsrg srg sr gsfg fdg</p>
          </div>
         <div class="maincontent_2">
           <p> fhgdohgoesh od uth iodo  ood  do doood oo dijtoid h toh doi dotoi  ho ohoh oih o
           </p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <div id="button_1">
        Click on me
      </div>
      <div id="button_2">
        Click on me again
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема в этих конструкциях:

```
if $('.maincontent_1' 'background-color') == 'blue';
```

Все-таки для упрощения чтения кода лучше использовать фигурные скобки. Это лишь мое мнение, но у вас именно из-за этого ошибки (ну и точка с запятой не нужна в конце if). Нужно так:

```
if ($('.maincontent_1').css('background-color') == 'blue'){
...
}
```

Правда, здесь всегда будет `false`, так как `.css()` возвращает цвет в формате RGB. Можно сравнивать как-то так: `== 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'`

UPD. Да, ошибся, `.css('background-color')` — формат цвета зависит от браузера.

Comment: _.css() возвращает цвет в формате RGB_ - это от браузера может зависеть

Comment: Поэтому не надо использовать цвет в качестве флага.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, и правда, не подумал даже...